# vb.NET location as string

Tags: vb.net, string

So..
when code is:

```
client.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("http://web.net/file.zip"), "C:\location\file.zip")
```

it is working, downloading file, but when it is like this:

```
Dim where As String = My.Computer.Registry.GetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\fsx\", "SetupPath", Nothing) + "\file.zip"
        client.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("http://web.net/file.zip"), where)
```

it isn't doing anything and no errors too.. what problem may be?

Comment: Did you work on a 64bit OS and your app is compiled for x86 platform?

Comment: I checked, string "where" is correct location

Comment: Can you post the where string